# Design best practices in sorting data in c# or SQL or both prior to Smartsheet Updates / Inserts

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I'm updating / inserting new records into a Smartsheet.

The data needs to be sorted by default prior to these inserts / updates.

I'm currently using a clustered index - insert with order by on my SQL Tables and sorting the data table in my Smartsheet API integration.

This is a duplicate effort and I'm not sure if this would follow good design, should I drop the clustered index - insert with order by and solely sort in the API integration? I figured this would help avoid maintenance on index fragmentation. Also, pardon my inexperience I'm not 100% certain that the clustered index and insert with order by clause will ensure my records are loaded appropriately.

Any suggestions would be great!

Thank you,
Channing

Comment: SQL server does not save data in any particular order.  It is multi-threaded and results comes back random.  So any query you do should include an OrderBy so you get results back every time in same order.

Comment: If you need a way to ensure that the results you `INSERT` can be returned in the same order, then you need a column within the data your inserting that can return the data in the same order. If you're querying a table with a `CLUSTERED INDEX` without using an `ORDER BY` there is no guarantee that the data will be returned in the same order, and any time it is is pure coincidence. As the table get's larger, queries get more complex, other indexes are used, etc, the chances of the coincidence severely diminish too.

Comment: Thank you all, so I am inserting into a table with a clustered index on the column I want sorted. In that insert I am ordering by said column in my select statement. I guess what I'm getting at is am I being inefficient by doing this on the server and client side?

Comment: Are you passing the value for the Clustered index? Are there already values in the table? If yes to both, are the new values sequential after the existing data?

Comment: I'm currently truncating the table and then re-inserting the data (with an order by) that would then be loaded into Smartsheet.